# Variable not declared in the scope, but works ("inference"??)

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

The syntax below works in a project in Visual Studio 2017, .NET 4.5.
This same syntax does not work on another machine, with Visual Studio 2015, .NET 4.5.
I do not know this syntax (for me 'eventargs' does not exist in that scope).
Is there any update in C # where it might be inferring 'eventargs'?
I did not find anything about it...

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is Telerik.XamarinForms.Input.AutoComplete.SuggestionItemSelectedEventArgs eventArgs))
            throw new ArgumentException("Expected SuggestionItemSelectedEventArgs as value", nameof(value));

        return eventArgs;
    }
```

Comment: its pattern matching - look after the `is`'s type

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching

Comment: Its part of the pattern matching syntactic sugar. If the is cast is successful, it is a typed variable of the tested type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a C# 7 feature called [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching), introduced with the compiler in Visual Studio 2017.

Basically `eventArgs` is declared with the `is` expression.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel A. White.